# dropwizard and hive/hiverunner integration with maven

Tags: maven, hive, jersey, swagger, dropwizard

most of the `dropwizard:0.9.2` maven dependencies use `glassfish jersey 2`:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:jar:2.22.1:compile
```

`org.apache.hive:hive-service:1.2.1` and `com.klarna.hiverunner:3.1.0` both use `com.sun.jersey 1`:

```
com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.9:runtime
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: io.dropwizard.jersey.setup.JerseyServletContainer-2acbc859@570b3305==io.dropwizard.jersey.setup.JerseyServletContainer,1,false

Caused by: A MultiException has 3 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.NullPointerException
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: method inject on com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$App
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory
```

I get the following if I exclude `jersey-core` from `hive`:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2.init(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf;)V
```

The goal is to set up an in-memory `hive` using `hiverunner` then write stuff to `hiveDB` (`Derby`) using `dropwizard` API endpoints.

Looks like `jersey 2` stopped using `jersey 1`'s `JSONJAXBContext`.
Is there a proper way to get around this `jersey 1 & 2` dependency conflict?

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution?